# Password Error with git and OSX keychain

Tags: macos, git, keychain

I am trying to push some changes in my repository. Whenever I enter git push, it asks for my passsword. WHen I enter my git password, i get an error saying

[image]

with options "cancel" and "Reset to defaults".

Now I click on "reset to defaults" then I am asked again.

[image]

Now i clicked on "reset". Now I am asked for a password. Here i experience a strange problem.
I tried my OSX password, git password , both dosn't works. I even changed the password of the keychain "login", event that is not being accepted.

[image]

How can I reset my git and keychain so that i dont encounter this error. 
What to do ?

thanks 
regards.

Comment: Can you access the general keychain and its contents, if you run the keychain application, or does the same dialog appear asking to create the new keychain?

Comment: Yes. I can access. Everything else is normal

Comment: Try deleting the github keychain: https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain

Comment: I have deleted all the keys. Created login keychain again. Still no success.